# What are set views in express?

Tags: node.js, express, view

I see this line of code

```
expressapp.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

I console log the value and here is the result:

> /Volumes/Workspace/local/nodejs/abc/views

But i can't find views folder in the project folder
I don't understand what does it mean even after looking at express document site:

```
A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.
```

What are application's views?

Answer (score 1):

Express look for the view inside /folder/views and

You can use the method set() to redefine express's default settings

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/yourViewDirectory');
```

Comment: What are views? html files? right after this line, i see the line: `expressapp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))` ,and inside public folder are html files. So what're views ?

Comment: "views" it is a folder/directory which contain the html files, and express looks for the "views" folder as default when it uses template engine, and u can also change the path as i mentioned in my post

Comment: Like i said, what's the line of code behind it? `public` is the folder that contains html files. Can you explain the different between these lines of code?

Comment: public and template engine are different, if u mentioned public, it gives access for your files. but not for templates. you are displaying the html files using template engine, so u should give the exact path. and one more info : the pages are directly render from the server side using res.render

Comment: But i cant find any views folder in my project folder. Removing this set views line is ok?

Comment: If u removed the set views, u ll get the lookup error